# How to analysis

Tags: regression

My research  has three independent variables but some of the dependent variables act as an independent for my objective 
Eg. the type of stroke affects the outcomes of stroke and both are affected by the age and gender 
The nursing management is the 3rd outcome variable which affect the stroke patients outcome which is also affected by the type of stroke and the age and the clinical presentations of the patient.
So how can I analysis this type?

Comment: Welcome to CV! You need to provide a lot more information in order to get some response. Start with what you are doing or trying to do; the more specific your question is regarding to statistics, the more answers you can expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you take the dependent variable to be outcome of stroke, and say we want to understand how it depends on the independent variables age, gender, type of stroke and nursing.

Now, if we regress outcome of stroke on all these variables we have a problem because the type of stroke affects nursing and vice-versa so there may be co-linearity there. It may be better then to first regress type of stroke on nursing and then include the residual from this regression into the original regression rather than the nursing variable. You can do these for any combination of "dependent" variables you decide to treat as independent.

Second problem is endogeneity - your "dependent" variable may cause your "independent" variable. There are a number of ways to handle this. I would suggest searching instrumental variables (IV) regression as this is a popular technique to handle this sort of issue in Economics and Finance.